# Problems uploading files to Amazon s3 bucket from a website on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3

Im in the process of moving my Django website to Heroku. But I can’t figure out how to use Heroku with Amazon s3 buckets. Previously I used to save all uploaded files in the project, but I can’t do that using Heroku.

I have been following the documentation on Heroku: [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3](http://heroku%20s3) and [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python](http://S3%20File%20Uploads%20in%20Python)
The bucket is located in Frankfurt.

When uploading a file I get the following error:

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
    <Message>a non-empty Access Key (AKID) must be provided in the credential.</Message>
    <ArgumentName>X-Amz-Credential</ArgumentName>
    <ArgumentValue>/20180502/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request</ArgumentValue>
    …
</Error>
```

I have specified the keys in Heroku like this: "heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyy"

You can go to https://eventcollective.herokuapp.com/accounts/account/ and try to upload an image.

**from views.py**

```
def sign_s3(request):
        S3_BUCKET = os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET')
        print(S3_BUCKET)

        file_name = request.GET.get('file_name')
        file_type = request.GET.get('file_type')

        s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-central-1')

        presigned_post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
            Bucket=S3_BUCKET,
            Key=file_name,
            Fields={"acl": "public-read", "Content-Type": file_type},
            Conditions=[
                {"acl": "public-read"},
                {"Content-Type": file_type}
            ],
            ExpiresIn=3600
        )
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
        'data': presigned_post,
        'url': 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s' % (S3_BUCKET, file_name)
    }))
```

Do you have any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I have to add "aws_access_key_id" and "aws_secret_access_key" when creating the client object.

```
s3 = boto3.client(
        's3',
        region_name='eu-central-1',
        aws_access_key_id='KEY',
        aws_secret_access_key='KEY',
    )
```